# Waterfall Simulation looks terrible

Tags: fluid-simulation

Why looks my waterfall so terrible. The mesh isnt even stick together. It splits to often and i cant figure out why. I also backed with 300 but it doesnt matter. The splits are so annyoing unrealistic.

[image]

Inflow looks like this (Its the top box)
[image]